# How to support transportMode motor-cycle using Calculate-Route API (here.com)

Tags: here-api

For *Here.com*'s [Calculate Route API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html), we are using `routingMode` as a mandatory parameter. *routingMode* contains a `transportMode` as a sub-parameter, [see the docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html#type-transport-mode).
But the **supported *transportMode*** must be exactly one of the following *enum* values :

- car
- pedestrian
- carHOV
- publicTransport
- publicTransportTimeTable
- truck
- bicycle

Our requirement is to use the *Calculate Route API* for **motor cycle**.

Please suggest how to use the API with a `transportMode` similar as **motorcycle**.

Comment: Your __ambiguaity__ is comprehensible. But what are your pro/con's for either using `car` or `bicycle`? What have you tried? Does the _resulting route_ look useful when using alternative `car` ? Seems like you are **asking for best-practice** on: _Which of given `transportMode best fits when route is used by motor-cicle?_

Answer (score 1):

Motor cycles also use car HOV lanes in all countries and have the same rules of a car. So you can use car or carHOV as the transport mode to calculate routes for motor cycles.

Comment: Does this link [Transport Mode](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/transport-modes.html) explain the applied _routing-rules_ in detail? Maybe you could explain what are the differences for either `car` or `carHOV` used in case of motor cycles and when to use the other of them.

Comment: They are inline with global HOV definitions. You can look up at wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-occupancy_vehicle_lane